# Increasing sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came across this question in a Real Analysis book and i dont have a any idea about how to start it.

Given $ X,Y > 0,\ X+Y=1,\ 0<x_1\le X.$ Recursively define $$x_{n+1}=X+Yx_n^3$$
Find if $(x_n)$ converges or not.

I know it is that it is increasing only.

Comment: Is this sequence bounded? You may want to use induction.

Comment: @Shahab this what i cannot figure out. It is bounded above by X. So can i prove by induction that $x_n \le 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $x_n\le 1$. Then $x_n^3\le 1$ and so $X+Yx_n^3\le X+Y= 1$ so by induction the sequence is bounded above by $1$.

Comment: thank you. Just to confirm the sequence is a increasing one right?

Comment: I am not sure. Please include your proof by editing the question.